# How do I Falcon Punch?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

Captian Falcon can Falcon Punch as one of his attacks. I believe it's the side special.

However, he sometimes says it when I use his up special, so I am not sure if it's really the up special, or I was just mashing buttons at the time.

How do I use Falcon Punch, and how do I get Captain Falcon to say the line?

Comment: Falcon Punch is Captain Falcon's neutral B special. It's pretty recognizable. If you aren't able to reproduce this on your own game, it's possible that your controller isn't working properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to push every button one at a time and see which one did the falcon punch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I Falcon Punch? *Super Smash Bros Brawl*

Captain Falcon's Falcon Punch is the Neutral Special, documented [here](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Falcon_Punch).

> Falcon Punch is Captain Falcon's Neutral Special Move in the Super Smash Bros. series. The move consists of Captain Falcon throwing a powerful punch, with his fist engulfed in a Falcon-shaped flame.

The Neutral Special Move button is bound by default to the B button, and can be referenced [here](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Neutral_Special_Move).

> The Neutral Special Move (also commonly referred to as Standard Special Move, Neutral B, or simply B) is a Special Move performed by pressing the special move button without holding a direction on the control stick. Many of these moves are projectiles, which can be used repeatedly to rack up damage indirectly and/or hinder the enemy's approach.